# Airport Extreme BCM4331 not recognised on FreeBSD

Tags: wifi, drivers, freebsd, bsd-ports, proprietary-drivers

So I have recently installed FreeBSD 10.1 (now UEFI native!) on my Mid-2012 MacBook Pro. The install went fine, except for one problem: my wireless card wasn't recognised. I looked into [`bwi`](//www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bwi) and [`bwn`](//www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bwn) as drivers, and selected `bwn`. I installed the required firmware from ports (as outlined in the man page), added it to [`loader.conf`](//www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=loader.conf), reebooted, and...

...nothing. Still wasn't detected, even after a manual re-scan in [`bsdconfig`](//www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdconfig). Upon further inspection (and PCI probes), I discovered that the card was actually being identified correctly, but had no driver associated with it.

So, does the `bwn` driver even support this model card? Should I use something else?

NOTE: I have come across many possible "solutions" on my internet research, but none have worked. Any advice is appreciated, but something that you actually *know* works would be best. Has anyone done this before? Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: The proper solution is of course to find and install the correct driver and your problems will be over.

Comment: @mdpc Any idea what this "proper driver" would be?